# Should Homework Questions Cite Their Textbook When Relevant?

Tags: discussion

I couldn't help noticing that hosting homework questions from textbooks borders on copyright infringement. Especially when [pictures of diagrams are used](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/46805/rotational-dynamics-problem-rod-slipping-against-block?rq=1). Is/should there be a policy promoting citing the textbook of origin, Chapter/section and question number? This might make it easier for others searching the internet for other problems in the same book as well.

Answer (score 9):

As a matter of copyright/plagiarism, then yes, whenever material is quoted verbatim from a textbook, or from anywhere really, the source should be identified. I think that is mentioned in our [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714), but if not, it should be added.

I would not expect this to be a "prosecutable" violation of copyright law, since quoting part or all of a homework problem for the purpose of getting help solving it probably falls under the fair use exception. (But I'm not a lawyer.)

Comment: Note that it is not our duty to police this. But it's always good to avoid issues in the first place.

Comment: It's mentioned, under "3. Reference the source".